# Find the lowest sum path through a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of data X where rows are time stamps and columns are measurements.  I can easily find the lowest sum path through the matrix by:

```
[r c]=size(X)
for w=1:r
Y(w)=min(X(w,:))
end

result = sum(Y)
```

this is useful, but what would be really useful is if there were a function that could  tell me different paths for a specified frequency.  For example if i group 2 rows together this halves the frequency...... If there was a function that could find me different paths with varying frequencies for a specified tolerance then rank them this would be perfect!

A lot to ask but there must be a statistical or mathematical tool that does this......

Comment: You do not need to loop to compute independent mins like this.  Just use `Y=min(X, [], 2);`  The 2 means to compute the min over the second dimension rather than the first.  MATLAB is a great tool for the job.  But your problem statement is extremely specific to your application, so you'll have to write the code yourself.  Start by specifying your problem more exactly.  What does "group" mean, exactly?  How does a tolerance play in to the minimum computation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I entirely understand the question, but if I read what you want this should do the trick for a fixed frequency:

```
frequency = 2;
r = size(X,1);
Y = zeros(r,1);
for w=1:frequency:r
Y(w)=min(min(X(w:w+frequency-1,:)))
end

result = sum(Y)
```

You can loop over frequencies to find the best path length for each frequency.

Note that finding the optimal path with varying frequencies (so for example first 2 then 3 then 2 again) would be a completely different problem. I think this is much more complex and that you may want to look into linear programming.

Comment: This assumes that you want the lowest value from each `frequency` rows. If you have to 'pass' through every row but just want to decide where on every `frequency` you can achieve this by replacing `min(min` with `min(sum`